# How to not overly aggressively police against spammers

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer today, to a question I found interesting. The answer started:

> This is my favorite weird constexpr issue: [the constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/) resolved by [P2280](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html).
>
> [... *multiple paragraphs of text follow, including suggestions of workarounds* ...]

The answer was edited to say:

> This is my favorite weird constexpr issue. I've written about it at my blog here: [The constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/); it was resolved by [P2280](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html).

I did not like that phrasing, so I rolled it back. I'm generally very cool with people editing my answers (especially to fix my endless stream of typos), but this read awkwardly, I think it's pretty obvious from clicking on the link that it's my blog. Also the editor didn't feel the need to attribute my paper, and I don't think the attribution is in any way relevant to the answer. Both the blog and the paper are just extended, detailed discussions of the problem at hand that the OP of the question might find useful. I am trying to be helpful.

The edit got rolled back again. I rolled it back and left a comment politely requesting to stop editing my answer. The answer then got multiple downvotes and I got multiple users downvoting the answer alleging that linking to my own blog post without explicit attribution violates the [spammer guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for self-promotion.

When the original question was closed as a duplicate, to a better worded, more active question (my bad for not searching), I posted a similar version of the answer to the more active question since it provides added useful context and information to the other answers that already existed. That answer was somehow downvoted to -5 and removed (edit: the answer has since been undeleted, so I've removed the link).

This strikes me as way, *way* too overeager policing. Linking to my own blog post for added context and information for answers, without explicitly saying that it's mine, is not spam. It is not self-promotion (hell, not only do I generate no revenue from the blog, I'm not sure I've even set up analytics properly to track how many views I get... I'm sure it's in the *dozens*). It is not being a snake oil salesman. And it's not even a link-only answer; the answers have other context that is not entirely included within the link.

I really do not think the original answer merited downvoting, editing, or deleting. I do not know what problem we are solving here.

Comment: Do note that a spam flag automatically down votes the post, the users might not have down voted at all.

Comment: This doesn't make me feel particularly motivated to write answers about C++ features added by papers I authored.

Comment: What you did isn't *fine*; removal of the disclosure was incorrect.

Comment: @ThomA Why? It's not self-promotion - there is nothing to... promote. It's not a product. Does T.C. have to disclose that he is affiliated with cppreference for every cppreference link he puts in his answers? Or whenever he links to the C++ draft? Cause he doesn't (because that requirement would be absurd), is somebody going to go flag and edit all of his answers now in the name of purity?

Comment: @ThomA Does Jonathan Wakely need to explicitly mention that he's the libstdc++ maintainer in all of his answers because it's an affiliated product? Because I'm sure he does not do so in every single one of his answers.

Comment: If they are explicitly suggesting a user uses that library/tool instead of others, probably. I suspect, however, that a post you are viewing is where a user has asked about that library and they have answered their question about it. There's no promotion there.

Comment: @Barry This isn't based on what your definition of spam is or even what the general definition of spam is. This is based on what Stack Overflow's definition of spam is. On the [promotion page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), it explicitly states: "if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer (or any other contribution to the site), you *must* disclose your affiliation in your post."

Comment: Additionally, you were given a link to this page in the comments by multiple people (myself included), which also explicitly said that you needed to disclose affiliation or your answers could *potentially* be deleted as spam. Only after you not only ignored these comments but even removed the disclosure that someone else added (minutes after at least my comment was posted, mind you) did your first answer get downvoted and your second deleted.

Comment: @Jesse ... in a paragraph whose context is about overt self-promotion, talking about answers about "about your product of website." It's even called "the promotion page." The answer isn't *about* my product or website, and it doesn't, overtly or otherwise, promote me.

Comment: @Jesse Also if you're going to aggressively timeline me, keep in mind that events happen asynchronously to different observers. I did not see the comments before I reverted the edits. I did not notice my other answer being deleted until far later, when I couldn't find it.

Comment: "but this read awkwardly, I think it's pretty obvious from clicking on the link that it's my blog" I can't even begin to imagine the argument for either of these claims. "Well the two answers there certainly suggest strongly that what I did was fine" - this, neither.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Huh? There's only one claim in that quote. Or are you suggesting that I now have to defend my subjective opinion of how my own answers are worded to my own personal taste? Perhaps I should open a poll on here every time I write an answer to decide between different grammar elements?

Comment: It shouldn't require leaving the site to determine that the link was to content you wrote.

Comment: That many people can figure something out != obvious. Aside from that, we *require by policy* the attribution to be *explicit and on-site* - which is consistent with many other policies; Stack Overflow content is expected to be able to stand on its own if anything happens to the content at the link.

Comment: I get the impression that you aren't actually here to *learn* where you went wrong, at this point, only to tell us (the community) that they were wrong... I'm out.

Comment: @ThomA Well, I was told that where I went wrong was violating a rule about overt self-promotion. A rule that I have never seen enforced in this way before, and will almost certainly never see enforced in this way again. Enforcing this rule is a choice, and it is a choice that strikes me as hostile especially towards the people who are best suited to provide answers to certain kinds of questions. That's why I'm here.

Comment: @ThomA It also doesn't help that "learning where I went wrong" apparently involves having to justify things like... my word choice preference? My word choice preference is not a claim, it's my word choice preference.

Comment: Removing affiliation information *entirely* isn't word choice preference. That you state that you think it is demonstrates you haven't understood the response here, or don't want to. I would like to assume the former.

Comment: Well, this has been educating. I'm pretty sure that a large number of my answers 1) are about some C++ standard library feature I authored, 2) link to cppreference where I'm an admin, or 3) link to my HTML version of C++ standard draft hosted on github. I guess I should start flagging them for deletion then. Too bad I can't just delete them myself.

Comment: @T.C. The rules for what requires disclosure of affiliation are a bit complex. I'd prefer not to go into detail *in comments*, because it requires quite a bit more text (trying to distill more than a decade worth of MSO and MSE posts) than can be contained in a comment. I do recognize that more detail is needed here in an answer. However, that said, disclosure is not *required* for links to official documentation when the question is directly about the thing which is being linked to. In such cases, disclosure is recommended (and often is beneficial to an answer), but isn't required.

Comment: I cleared the spam flags on your second answer. As a result, the post is now unlocked. You can go ahead and edit disclosure of affiliation into the post, as required by site rules.

Comment: "A rule that I have never seen enforced in this way before, and will almost certainly never see enforced in this way again." - I can't really imagine how exactly you would expect to be able to "see" the rule being enforced against someone else.

Comment: @T.C. "I guess I should start flagging them for deletion then. Too bad I can't just delete them myself." - or you could... **edit them**?

Comment: @Barry it's kinda hard to see your avatar on your blog without going to it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I consider "disclosures" related to the mentioned things noisy, distracting and of negative value, and in some cases they can be incorrectly perceived as an appeal to authority or as bragging. So, no, I'm not editing them. If the rules require them, I'll follow the rules by deleting the answer.

Comment: People post content that is SE spam or SE over-promotion. These things cost investigation by curating users. Disclosure rules reduce that waste. Effort writing & reading posts following disclosure rules is the cost of a larger savings.

Comment: The meta does get too trigger-happy enforcing the rules sometimes. :/ Even if the rule does ultimately make sense, being nicer to a fellow user while enforcing it helps a lot.

Comment: *"This strikes me as way, way too over-eager policing"* - regardless of the context, this is what will happen on Stack Overflow. There is no stopping a user base this huge. I don't even call it over-eager, it's just a great many people in isolation clicking buttons, blissfully unaware of others doing the same thing. The anti-Borg, the bee nest without a  hive mind, no possibility to persuade it to change it's way unless someone with great authority says not to do it and it becomes a bannable offence. Even if you persuade meta... nothing changes. Meta is but a small very vocal minority.

Comment: @T.C. FWIW, mass-deletion of your own content, especially out of spite, is _also_ against the rules.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that goes both ways. OP has also been way overly aggressive and absolutely not nice at all.

Comment: @VLAZ It's very difficult to be nice to people when they are behaving towards you the way that several people in this thread are behaving towards me. When this started, I left a note asking people to please stop editing my answer - which led to getting piled on, downvoted, and having an answer straight up deleted. Now, I have people in this thread accusing me of acting in bad faith and misrepresenting statements I've made. This has been an incredibly frustrating experience for me - all stemming from... trying to write a helpful answer? But yeah. I'm the one that hasn't been nice at all.

Comment: @Barry yes. In the future, if you want to protest something, don't also exemplify it. As somebody who has written a paper, you should really be well acquainted with referencing other works - be they yours or not. Yet you're here telling people they are wrong for requiring you to...reference what you wrote, according to the guidelines of this site. And are combatting that this is something you should even do. So, "aggressive" is what you don't want people to be, yet I struggle to use a more apt descriptor for the way you've approached it.

Comment: @VLAZ Expressing disagreement is now "aggressive" and "combatting"? This is Meta, I thought half the point of the existence of this part of the site was to be able to express disagreement. I'm not telling people they're wrong for requiring *me personally* to do this. I am trying to express the opinion that aggressively applying this disclosure rule without regard to the broader context of whether the answer in question is even vaguely overt self-promotion or spam is harmful. I think context happens to matter. That is all.

Comment: @Barry you've done more than "express disagreement". And yes, it has been aggressive.

Comment: Mini-Feedback, I kind of _sympathize_ with your Scenario, but I also/already find your Title for this Thread pretty "aggressive" ("*How to not overly aggressively police against spammers*") (+ missing '?' for asking a Qt, grrr...!). // Maybe a "better"/less_asking_for_DV's Title could be: "How to not aggressively flag as Spam an Answer containing a Link to a (more) detailed Paper on my Blog?" // But you'll always need to disclose ownership of that Blog of yours, I don't understand your "stubbornness"/refusal about that in the whole Thread...

Comment: @chivracq Do you believe that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794224/performance-of-simple-c20-coroutines-looks-bad-is-this-unavoidable-is-this-c#comment137156015_77794830) is overt self-promotion or spam and should be flagged and removed due to lack of disclosure? Do you believe the adding of disclosure would add anything of value to the comment whatsoever? My "stubbornness" stems from the fact that my answers to those questions are both, very obviously, no.

Comment: @chivracq The cited rule does not talk about links at all, it uses the word _mention_ (and I linked to one comment, Wakely's - at least the link for me directly goes there). So it's a perfectly valid comparison.

Comment: Okay, I only posted my (first) Comment to give you some Feedback about the Title you've chosen for this current Thread/Qt, I don't care about following (irrelevant) Links to my Feedback... feels a bit like you only want to argue for the sake of arguing, while I said, I kind of understand/support your Cause...  // But OK, good luck, I'm out...

Answer (score 36):

<sup>N.B. your spam-deleted answer has since had its spam flags canceled and been undeleted by a moderator. As for the matter of disclosure in posts...</sup>

It's a site rule that you need to explicitly disclose affiliation in your posts. That's not 'overly aggressively policing', it's complying with the site rules.

> Linking to my own blog post for added context and information for answers, without explicitly saying that it's mine, is not spam.

Yes, it is, if you don't disclose that affiliation. From the opening paragraph on the Help Center (AKA The Site Rules) page for [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. *However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer (or any other contribution to the site), **you must disclose your affiliation in your post.***

Emphasis mine.

Do I think a spam flag is warranted for such an omission? At the outset, no, but if you insist on removing the site rules-mandated affiliation, I can see how a user might get upset about that and just flag it for spam and let a moderator handle it from there.

Pretty much *any* resource or prior question you find on the subject, including the one linked above by Thom A, is going to say, either explicitly or implicitly, that you need to disclose your affiliation, and for good reason. Doing so is a tiny act that helps make it clear to readers that there is a potential conflict of interest. Even if (big if) one could argue successfully that disclosure is not always necessary, removing that disclosure when it was *already there* is **never** helpful, *only* harmful.

The only thing *removing* disclosure of affiliation does is obfuscate a potential conflict of interest. And that... makes you look like a spammer.

Comment: Your points are valid here about declaring affiliation, but *spam* is wrong; that has a very clear definition on [so], and the post linked isn't spam. If a rollback "war" (about affiliation) occured, then a custom flag should have been raised.

Comment: @ThomA Undisclosed affiliation is considered spam according to the site. The goal of the spam is irrelevant.

Comment: What about the linked answer "Exists only to promote a product or service"?

Comment: I'm hard pressed to understand by what definition my link counts as "overt self-promotion." Ironically, the lack of saying "READ MY AWESOME BLOG POST" makes it hard to be any kind of self-promotion...

Comment: @ThomA Modal text is often less than ideal, I commiserate with you on that; I've been wanting our close vote reasons to be reverted back to the old, far better, reasons for years. That being said, Help Center articles trump the blurb used to describe a flag. And I don't know how more clear I can be than "here's the Help Center page on spam, which explicitly states not to do what you have described doing in your post".

Comment: I cannot agree with you, @Tyler. Spam is *spam*; it is only there to advertise *something*. The OP answer was not that; they provided an answer and simply didn't disclose affiliated to a **related** blog post. If that link were removed, it wouldn't be spam either. The spam flags were *wrong*; unless the OP is also affiliated to the other links as well.

Comment: @ThomA Take it up with the site, then, I guess. It's their rules, definition, and practices you need to get changed. OP is complaining about an edit that added explicit affiliation disclosure to a link to OP's blog, not someone else's. They even argue that it should be obvious that it is their blog and thus explicit disclosure is not needed.

Comment: I agree on that it's not immediately obvious, even implicitly. The only way you could infer would be that the authors share the same (first) name; which is not enough for implicit disclosure.

Comment: @ThomA Or, say, notice the same avatar. Also, it was obvious enough for people to aggressively police it as self-promotion - so I think the claim is kind of proven true.

Comment: @Barry You're missing the important, overarching point here. One cannot rely on intuition in terms of 'will _someone else_ know whether and to what extent I am affiliated with this link'. That's precisely why we have a rule which, as this answer clearly shows, states you need to disclose that affiliation always, no matter what.

Comment: @TylerH Where I am stuck though is _why it is relevant who is affiliated with this link_. It is not a product that I am selling. I derive no more value from people reading that post than I derive from people reading an answer I post here. It is extremely hostile to me to cite a rule about self-promotion to attack me about an answer that doesn't even promote me.

Comment: @TylerH Also I have never seen this rule enforced before in this way, and I will almost certainly continue to not see it enforced in this way (see the examples I cited earlier about cppreference and libstdc++). This seems very far from the actual point of the rule (which is, as the rule says, to combat overt self-promotion)

Comment: @Barry if you want to request that the community change a rule, you can do that. But that's not what you're doing in this post. In this post you're complaining about users who are simply enforcing site rules, and refusing to acknowledge that the behavior violated said rules in the first place. My final advice here: you are in a hole. Quit digging.

Comment: @TylerH Just to pipe in with some more sources, [the help center page on flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) links to [the Meta SE FAQ post on spam and R&A flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) as the definitive source on what is and isn't spam, which states explicitly that "_A post should be marked as spam only if it promotes a product, service, or similar; **and** is unsolicited or lacks disclosure of affiliation._". The discrepancy seems mostly to do with whether linking your own site as a source counts as "promoting" it in a meaningful way.

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks--my answer here doesn't address the user's spam-deleted answer, just the one that had multiple disclosure edits and multiple subsequent rollbacks, and that general topic.

Comment: @TylerH what you are doing is discussing so called "the rule" instead of discussing the case. The case is clear: someone posted the link with the right information (it doesn't matter who owns the website or who wrote the text, what matters is whether the information correct or not). Nobody advertised anything, nobody promoted anything, just gave the answer and that's it. No spam in any way. That's what important and not "the rule" you always reference to.

Comment: @Dmitry What a ridiculous comment. I am applying "the rule" to "the case" as described by the OP. That's how the world works. That you disagree with the rule is not our problem.

Comment: @TylerH and may I ask if you can prove that "the rule" is correct? Here I assume any wrong rules are not applicable by definition

Comment: @Dmitry I **literally** linked to the rule page and quoted the relevant text _with emphasis_. Did you read my answer?

Comment: @Dmitry A rule is a rule. Whether or not you think it's "correct" is irrelevant. If you break the law, you'll still be arrested regardless of whether or not you agree with it.

Comment: @Jesse dogmatical belief in any rule is a religion (not knowledge). If that's a case I have nothing to say.

Comment: @Dmitry That's why courts and judges exist (in this case, this site and mods). If you don't like the rules, do something about it instead of questioning the people that enforce them.

Comment: That is actually _not_ how the world works. @Dmitry is correct. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Newyorkbrad/Newyorkbradblog#Clear_remedies,_arbitration_decisions,_and_AE) is a good and relevant read on the business of interpreting what rules are intended to mean. You are correct that the **one sentence** that you **literally** quoted _with emphasis_ means what you say it means, but the broader context of the entire page is clearly intended to combat an issue with is wholly irrelevant in this particular context. Enforcing rules is always a choice.

Comment: @Barry The broader context of the page is preventing the kind of behavior you initiated. If you don't like the rules of this site, go elsewhere please.

Comment: @Barry [you've already been informed by a moderator that disclosure is needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427730/how-to-not-overly-aggressively-police-against-spammers#comment983604_427730). The case here is closed, there is no room for you to argue it does not apply to you. If you still disagree, then use the contact form and discuss this directly with staff.

Comment: @VLAZ Where can I find the contact form?

Comment: @Barry https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/ - can also be found at the bottom of the page - the "Contact Us" link under "Company".

Comment: @Barry I see that people here are indeed aggressive and even hostile, while saying you're aggressive and hostile. They regularly break their own self made rules, happily and publicly, when it suits their end goals. That being said, (1) I like rules being enforced by the letter and in spirit. (2) Rules are there for a reason. (3) `It is not a product that I am selling. I derive no more value from people reading that post than I derive from people reading an answer I post here.` Applying the spirit of the rule: (i) If I see a link,  how do I know you're not selling without clicking it? [1/2]

Comment: @Barry  (ii) What's stopping you from selling something or just placing ads there in the future? (iii) if you're promoting your own blog/github, doesn't that indirectly lead them to your other repos, which may get you stars, which in turn gets you more public recognition? Don't you get paid in intangible things like these?

Answer (score 19):

The edit to your post was correct; disclosure of links you are affiliated to is required. The edit to your post to denote that was actually a *good* edit and you should not have rolled it back or rejected it. If you were unhappy with the wording you could adjust it, but you needed to retain the disclosure as it's required.

As for the flagging of spam, this I disagree with; the post is not there to solely promote your work. If we removed that link it would still be an answer. If you did rollback that edit then a custom moderator flag should have been raised instead and a moderator would be able to inform you of the importance of including disclosure of affiliation.

If your post was purely to promote a specific product, which you might gain monetary funds as a result from (perhaps due to an affiliate link) I could more understand these flags; there is something for you to gain and affiliation disclosure is *so* important there. I don't see any malice here, and that's something moderators, and curators, should take into account.

A user in your deleted answer, however, does note that you more or less posted 2 very similar answers to promote the same page on your site; that is less "ok", and I can see why users would be less happy about it. Promoting it once is fine, prompting it twice shortly after the other, with similar (the same) wording, and lacking affiliation in both isn't. Looking at your [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2069064%20url%3abrevzin.github.io&searchOn=3), however, you don't actually promote your site often, so this seems more of an education issue rather than malice again; something that a custom moderator flag could have handled.

TL;DR: you were on the wrong side of the thin line here, but marginally (in my view). The reactions of the users, in my opinion, were incorrect in flagging as spam (a custom flag should have been used), but your actions to remove affiliation and repost the same content was incorrect too.

Comment: Separate from everything else, I did not "repost the same content." The two answers have same intro sentence, but the rest of the content differs, and are appropriately tailored to their respective questions. I do not see what about this is "incorrect."