What factors were considered for declining AI flag on Meta?
I flagged two of the Meta answers as having AI-generated content. Both were declined. Could I have some transparency on why the flags were declined?
Flags were raised by me on these two answers:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421832/
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421850/


>90% AI generated content. In the context of banning ChatGPT content, answers having ChatGPT content even for "comedic purposes" as a top answer seems openly flaunting and violating the policy in the question. If ChatGPT generated content is banned, it is also to be enforced here in meta and more importantly in this question, by example, regardless of the intention of the poster or the votes.

It was declined with the following response.

Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I am not sure what evidence was needed, since the OP openly admits using ChatGPT. So, I assumed maybe there is no evidence for "openly flaunting". So, I raised a flag on other answer without too much elaboration.

AI generated content present.

It was declined with the following response.

Declined - yeah, we're not going to delete this post. it is what it is.

Now, that's fine, if that's what moderators had decided. But what were the factors considered? I couldn't get more info without raising more declined flags. So, I'm asking this in Meta. Were these factors considered?

Intention of the poster
Purpose of the answer
Age of the answer
Vote of the answer
Reputation of the user posting the answer

Could the moderators elaborate on whether these or other factors were considered and why? Also, if an exception was made based on some specific factors, can such exceptions be made elsewhere in Meta or the Main site based on the same factors?

Pretty sure the exception is only because these were the first such answers on Meta. All further attempts (a lot in the same Q&A) have been removed.

Fun is not per se banned on meta. So that's why these two answers stayed on the site.

@VLAZ TBH, I don't see the logic in accounting the age of the answer for deciding whether it's against the rules. Some highly voted old questions in the main site is deleted, because they have become offtopic today(and probably was offtopic before too).  But, if mods say that's the only or one of the factors and that it is important to take the age of the question into account, I'll take their word for it.

@TheMaster historical locks exist even on main. They have for years. Leaving something which is off-topic but well received has been done for over a decade.

In context, those answers were appropriate and illustrative of the topic. We don't worship rules, the rules were created to serve our ends, not the other way around.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk  I don't believe executing the law in an unbiased manner is worship. The law is meant to provide a equal ground without bias to friends/family/reps/etc.  the rules were created to serve our ends Who is "our"? Just the Meta insiders? The Majority? The majority inside Meta? Would you say the same("We don't worship rules, the rules were created to serve our ends, not the other way around") in favor of OP here:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427730 ?

Those were very early answers. They were the first ones to "ironically" ask ChatGPT what it thought about being banned.
Back then, that kind of irony was still acceptable, and those 2 are just a historical exception.
Similar answers after those were all removed, as the joke has been made already.
To be honest, I don't really understand what makes you think answers with a score of 2554 and 1588 respectively have gotten through the cracks, and require a moderator flag for an AI ban, especially since those answers were locked by moderators...

Now, as for your bullet points:

Intention of the poster
The intention of the posts was to have a little fun. That's allowed on Meta, in moderation :D
Purpose of the answer
Same as the previous point... Fun.
Age of the answer
That only contributed in the sense that they were the first ones to make that joke.
Vote of the answer
That's not historically been a factor for those answers. They weren't deleted when they first got posted.
Reputation of the user posting the answer
I can guarantee you that the user's reputation has nothing to do with any of this, and to suggest as much is extremely unconstructive.


In other words, if the purpose is "fun" and it is in "meta" and if it is one of the first few(age), it is allowed, even if it breaks some rules in the process. Is that correct?

No. There's not a single hard rule about "fun". This is judged on a case-by-case basis. And frankly, it's incredibly presumptuous to flag answers that old, with that many upvotes, and expect them to be deleted.

The problem isn't that it is or isn't "fun" or whether "fun" is banned. The problem is if that "fun" breaks the rule(even the rule explicitly mentioned in the question), should a exception be made, if so, on what factors - on the age and that it is just "fun"?  It's not presumptuous to think Meta which makes the rules should follow them even if it goes against their "fun" - Shouldn't Meta lead by example? "We hate fun" and we do remove "fun" content as noise in the main site. Isn't it hypocritical for me to link to that question to a new user, while the top answer explicitly breaks it?

I think it's presumptuous to think you know better than the moderator who locked those answers, all the other moderators who deleted other AI answers, and the thousands of users that upvoted those 2 answers. You're asking for a black-and-white interpretation of the rules. That's unrealistic.

Where there are rules, there will be exceptions. These 2 answers are an exception. That's not hypocritical. That's life, that's community, that's culture.

I'm asking the criteria for such exception. I'm asking  for uniform impartial implementation of such exception. "Fun" clearly broke the rules. It is "black"  and there's no question about it. You can't judge one way for one scenario and another way for the same scenario. Exception was made. You're saying "fun" and "age" were  the reasons for this difference. Though I don't like it, if that's the official public policy made transparent by moderators, I'll accept it.

Purpose of the answers was not merely fun, but also proving the point that AI should not be allowed on Stack Overflow. Those answers also satisfy one important requirement attribution. They explicitly quote AI generated content.

@TheMaster Again, there's no "set in stone" criteria. "This is judged on a case-by-case basis." This isn't "official policy" that you can then apply to other answers. These 2 answers were just deemed to be an exception. Nothing more than that.

@DalijaPrasnikar Good point. I can see at least one of those answers making the sarcastic point that it answers both ways and that it shouldn't be trusted. In that case, I think removing "comedic/ironic purposes" would be better.
